# CUDA|RAM runs out of memory using Keras model.fit_generator

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, gpu

I have a video data input of the shape (300,226,226,3) with channel last configuration & my output is (300,1) stored as numpy array formats. As I don't want to load all the data at once as it is around 120GB. My code is pretty simple:

```
import os
import sys
from random import shuffle

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import (BatchNormalization, Dense, Flatten, Input,
                          MaxPooling3D, TimeDistributed)
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv3D
from keras.layers.convolutional_recurrent import ConvLSTM2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.utils import plot_model
from model import My_ConvLSTM_Model
import numpy as np
from random import shuffle
import pandas as pd
import os


def generate_arrays(available_ids):
    datar = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/muzaf/Documents/GitHub/Data_mining/data.csv")
    while True:
        for i in available_ids:
            name_ext = str(datar.iat[i, 0])
            name = os.path.basename((os.path.splitext(name_ext))[0])
            scene = np.load('D:/Webcam/Input/{}.npy'.format(name))
            category = np.load('output/{}.npy'.format(name))
            yield (np.array([scene]), category[0])


available_ids = [i for i in range(1, 20)]

shuffle(available_ids)

final_train_id = int(len(available_ids)*0.8)
train_ids = available_ids[:final_train_id]
val_ids = available_ids[final_train_id:]
frames = 300
pixels_x = 226
pixels_y = 226
channels = 3

seq = Sequential()
seq.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=20, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                   input_shape=(None, pixels_x, pixels_y, channels),
                   padding='same', data_format='channels_last', return_sequences=True))
seq.add(BatchNormalization())
seq.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 1), strides=None,
                          padding='valid', data_format='channels_last'))
seq.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
seq.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(32,)))
seq.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='relu')))
seq.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
print (seq.summary())
history = seq.fit_generator(
    generate_arrays(train_ids), steps_per_epoch=len(train_ids),
    validation_data=generate_arrays(val_ids),
    validation_steps=len(val_ids),
    epochs=100, verbose=1, shuffle=False, initial_epoch=0)
```

As soon as I run this, my GPU(GTX 1060:6GB) memory gets full & so is my RAM. AM I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

try to reduce steps_per_epoch & validation_steps. Putting all the data in ones will explode your memory. It's like defining batch size.

**steps_per_epoch**: Total number of steps (batches of samples) to yield from generator before declaring one epoch finished and starting the next epoch. It should typically be equal to the number of samples of your dataset divided by the batch size. Optional for Sequence: if unspecified, will use the len(generator) as a number of steps.

**validation_steps**: Only relevant if validation_data is a generator. Total number of steps (batches of samples) to yield from generator before stopping. Optional for Sequence: if unspecified, will use the len(validation_data) as a number of steps.

Comment: I have reduced them to one & changed the max_queue_size = 1. Plus I have two **GTX1080Ti with 12 GB memory**, do you think I should reduce it to half or further down?

Comment: Would you please post your seq.summary() output

Answer (score 0):

Batch size in Deep learning refers to the number of training examples utilized in one iteration.
You have given such a large batch size of 300. Just reduce the batch to a smaller number of 8,16,32 which is usually a practice in a deep learning experiment. Giving a large batch often leads to GPU out of memory because that much memory won't be available for processing a large batch of images.

One more reason that can lead to out of memory situations can be because of the presence of other processes running in the background. Just do `nvidia-smi` and see whether there are any processes running in the GPU. If yes then check the memory availability.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: But it is a sequential data, my training was supposed to happen on the whole video at a time. Plus I have two **GTX1080Ti with 12 GB memory** , do you think I should reduce it  to half or further down?

Comment: I think you should read about epochs, iterations and all in deep learning. Reducing your batch size has nothing to do whether you are going to train on whole video. Whether you give batch-size of 16 or 3000, whole video images will be covered in a epoch.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure no more browser applications is running such as Chrome, firefox, so on. Later, turn on the GPU-monitor tool to see its memory utilization for tuning the batch-size parameters. If still not work, try to reduce the size of the training data.